# Uncertain on How to Upgrade pgadmin

Tags: postgresql

Excuse me for my noobie question. I want to update to the latest version of pgadmin (on Windows). On the download page, it shows three files. What do each of those files do? I simply want to update my current version. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

https://www.postgresql.org/ftp/pgadmin/pgadmin4/v2.1/windows/

Comment: Just use the big file and ignore the others.

Comment: I assume that means the executable? Okay, thanks for your help.